# Can we run sonobuoy to be k8s conformance on a Rancher cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rancher, rancher-rke

We setup a rancher cluster with 3 nodes for testing and I would like to apply for k8s conformance using this rancher cluster. However, while running sonobuoy it returns error

```
ERRO[0000] could not create sonobuoy client: failed to get rest config: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided
```

It seems like Rancher does not have any kubernates binaries built-in (Kubectl, kubeadm etc). May I know if it is possible to be k8s conformance on a rancher cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You should have kubeernetes cluster  `kubeconfig` localy where you are running `sonobuoy`.

from Rancher documentation: [How to Manage Kubernetes With Kubectl](https://rancher.com/learning-paths/how-to-manage-kubernetes-with-kubectl/):

RKE:

> When you create a Kubernetes cluster with RKE, RKE creates a
> kube_config_rancher-cluster.yml file in the local directory that
> contains credentials to connect to your new cluster with tools like
> kubectl.
>
> You can copy this file to $HOME/.kube/config or, if you are working
> with multiple Kubernetes clusters

Rancher-Managed Kubernetes Clusters:

> Within Rancher, you can download a kubeconfig file through the web UI
> and use it to connect to your Kubernetes environment with kubectl.
>
> From the Rancher UI, click on the cluster you would like to connect to
> via kubectl. On the top right-hand side of the page, click the
> Kubeconfig File button: Click on the button for a detailed look at
> your config file as well as directions to place in ~/.kube/config.
>
> Upon copying your configuration to ~/.kube/config, you will be able to
> run kubectl commands without having to specify the –-kube-config file
> location:

Check [First launch with sonobuoy requests for a configuration](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/sonobuoy/issues/1015) - maybe it will be useful for you.

---

Also, look here - just for you: [Conformance tests for Rancher 2.x Kubernetes](https://github.com/cncf/k8s-conformance/blob/master/v1.13/rancher/README.md)

[Run Conformance Test](https://github.com/cncf/k8s-conformance/blob/master/v1.13/rancher/README.md)

1. Once you Rancher Kubernetes cluster is active, Fetch it's kubeconfig.yml file and save it locally.
2. Download a sonobuoy binary release of the CLI, or build it yourself by running:

   `$ go get -u -v github.com/heptio/sonobuoy`
3. Configure your kubeconfig file by running:

   `$ export KUBECONFIG="/path/to/your/cluster/kubeconfig.yml"`
4. Run sonobuoy:

   `$ sonobuoy run`
5. Watch the logs:

   `$ sonobuoy logs`
6. Check the status:

   `$ sonobuoy status`
7. Once the status commands shows the run as completed, you can download the results tar.gz file:

   `$ sonobuoy retrieve`